# Debugging an Erlang code with eunit in IntelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, erlang

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2

I set a breakpoint in my Erlang code which has eunit testcases.

In order to debug it, I clicked on "Run --> Debug". I got an error "Test suite was cancelled". What could be the reason?

```
"C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP\bin\erl.exe" -pa C:\Users\bhu\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij_erlang_debugger_7789 -pa C:/Users/bhu/AppData/Local/Temp/eunit_teamcity9 -pa F:/1TB/P/workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang1/out/test/workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang1 -pa F:/1TB/P/workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang1 -run debugnode main 50067 -noshell -s init stop
Testing started at 20:59 ...
** Invalid beam file or no abstract code: "F:\\1TB\\P\\workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang1\\src\\my_sort.erl"
Test suite was cancelled. Reason: {abort,{module_not_found,my_sort}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error means that the module `my_sort` was not loaded into the VM. You can find the [function here](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#module_loaded-1). I think this is because the search path to your module `my_sort` is not added to the code path using the flag `-pa /mypath/my_sort.erl`.

Could you try to add to the code path using `-pa ..`?